# Simple White Space HTML Minification for PHP

Tags: php, html, minify

I'm trying to find a simple minification example that will do the following:

1. Remove all whitespace left of each line
2. Remove all multiple newlines
3. Keep all other line breaks in tact.

So this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            //content here
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Would become this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
//content here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything on it's own line, no extra new lines.

I've found a bunch of more extreme minifiers such as this:

```
$search = array(
    '/\>[^\S ]+/s', // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
    '/[^\S ]+\</s', // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
    '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
);

$replace = array(
    '>',
    '<',
    '\\1'
);
```

But this goes way overboard for what I need.

Something simple would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode` each line into an array. Use `trim` to remove the whitespaces. Then use `array_filter` to remove empty lines. Finally join remaining elements together with `implode`.

```
function minify($html) {
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $html);
    array_walk($lines, function(&$line) {
        $line = trim($line);
    });

    $lines = array_filter($lines, function($line) {
        return $line !== '';
    });

    return implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/dG71fL

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing every sequence of white space characters with the first space character of the sequence works for your example, but I don't know about more complex html code.

```
$s = preg_replace("/(\s)\s+/", "$1", $s);
```